# Passing listBox to a new form

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, listbox

I have a problem with my constructor. I got it set up like this:

**Form1:**

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2(listBox1);
    form2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

**Form2:**

```
public Form2(ListBox listBox)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items=listBox.Items;
}
```

I just want to send my data from listBox on the Form1 to my Form2 listBox but it's giving me this error:

> Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: Well the error is self-explanatory. You can't set the `Items` property as it is read-only - have a read of the [docs] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to assign data to a listbox. Also, you should really rename `var form1` which is a *really* misleading variable name

Comment: Thank you but do you know how can i get the items from the listBox on the first form to the second one and show it in that lisBox. Im new to c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the answer from Sampath, which is completely correct. But for readability and shorter code, you can use the [**ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cdcdw5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public Form2(ListBox listBox)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(listBox.Items);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`listBox.Items` is read only property. You need to use `listBox.Items.Add() or AddRange()` method.

```
//From form1 pass only your listbox items.
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var form2 = new Form2(listBox1.Items);
            form2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }


//In your form2 you can use AddRange()
    public Racun(ListBox.ObjectCollection Items)
        {
            InitializeComponent();      

            listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);

        }
```

Comment: So it goes from this: listBox1.Items=listBox.Items; TO THIS: listBox1.Items.Add(listBox.Items);?

Comment: Why did you change your loop-solution to mine?! Yours was already correct.

Comment: This one didn't somehow work yours did. But you both helped me.